# Chrome Developer Tools. Classes not found in bootstrap.css file, and shows in the grid.less virtual file

Tags: less

To correctly replace the property, must be correctly understand the origin and perform override.

My results show that in the "Chrome Developer Tools, Ctrl + Shift + I" **class** **.container** not found in bootstrap.css file. It does not show the actual source. Why? How do I fix?

It shows stored in the grid.less file. Why is that file? Request for a non-existent file in the folder name.
Really @include requests can not be found in the bootstrap.

Demo search classes:

```
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Result:

grid.less:10

in ... css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/less/mixins/grid.less

```
.container-fixed(@gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left:  floor((@gutter / 2));
  padding-right: ceil((@gutter / 2));    // line 10 on grid.less
  &:extend(.clearfix all);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Chrome Developer Tools is likely reading the CSS Map Provided by Bootstrap.

You can either remove `bootstrap.css.map` from your resources or disable CSS Maps in the Chrome Developer Tools Settings `Preferences -> Sources -> Enable CSS Source maps`

After that the CSS should be read as is by Chrome Developer Tools.

Here you can read more on [Source Maps](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-source-maps) and how they are used